# pivot table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having problem for creating a pivot in MySQL

I have following table;

```
Month,id,name,partner,amount
01,1,xx,AA,100
01,1,xx,BB,200
```

I want to get following output from this table

```
Month,id,name,partner,amount ,partner, amount
01,1,XX,A,100,BB,200
```

I have tried different groupings but i am unable to convert two rows into one.

Comment: This is one of the things that's way easier to do in code than in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Something that is close to what you want (only the output is not split into fields) - untested

```
SELECT MONTH, ID, NAME, 
GROUP_CONCAT(INFO ORDER BY PARTNER SEPARATOR ',') AS INFO_LIST FROM (
    SELECT MONTH, ID, NAME, PARTNER, 
    CONCAT_WS(',', PARTNER, AMOUNT) as INFO FROM <yourtable>
) GROUP BY MONTH, ID ORDER BY MONTH, ID;
```

Comment: thanks for answer but i need data in separate columns

Comment: it is not something mysql can do for you in this case, I am afraid. Unless you can specify in advance how many columns there are going to be. And even in that case, the query will be quite clumsy, which is why I would rather do it in code.